# R - convert factor() column into a Binary Matrix Value

Tags: r, binary, integer

I am quite new to R, and I need R to recognize some of data as binary. So I made a survey and **I'd like R to analyze the Gender, Like, and Share columns as binary** - so I can ggplot them properly.

```
head(d)
  Gender Age Like Share
1   Male  26   No     2
2   Male  23  Yes     0
3 Female  21   No     4
4   Male  19   No     0
5 Female  20  Yes     0
6   Male  23   No     4
```

The thing is that I would like to evaluate if there's a corrolation between certain factors - and to do so, I want to do a regression line that would look like this. But the problem is that **I always get this error message**

```
M <- ggplot(data=d,aes(x=Age,colour=Share) + geom_point())

Error in aes(x = Age, colour = Share) + geom_point() : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

So if you could help me out with those two problems, that'd be awesome.
One last thing, I don't know if this could help, but in case, I'll give it to you ...

```
 sapply(D,class)
   Gender       Age      Like     Share 
"integer" "numeric" "integer" "integer"


sapply(D,mode)
   Gender       Age      Like     Share 
"numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: You just messed up the parenthesis and embeded `geom_point()` within `ggplot()`. You also need to specify the `y` argument within `ggplot()`.Try  for example `ggplot(data=d,aes(x=Age, y= Gender, colour=Share)) + geom_point()`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to make those categories binary would be something like this:

```
d$GenderBinary <- 0
d$GenderBinary[d$Gender == "Male"] <- 1
d$LikeBinary <- 0
d$LikeBinary[d$Gender == "Yes"] <- 1
```

Not sure how you expect to make a column with more than two categories binary, though ("Share").

For the ggplot error, it looks like you have forgotten to supply the y variable(s) (which presumably would be your binary variables).